# Quelle est la différence entre « procès » et « procédé » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

En cherchant une traduction français pour le mot anglais « process », dans le sens de « manufacturing process », j'ai trouvé ces deux mots équivalents : « procès » et « procédé ».

Est-ce que quelqu'un connait la différence/nuance entre ces deux mots ?
J'aimerais aussi savoir la différence entre eux et le mot « processus ».

Comment: Process en anglais veut dire en français un processus OU un procédé. Procès c'est proceedings or trial dans le domaine juridique. Process en anglais n'est jamais procès en français. Un procès dans un tribunal (trial or proceeding). Alors, votre source se trompe.

Comment: A manufacturing process is a procédé de fabrication. Mais, évidemment un manufacturing process peut également être une processus de fabrication. Donc, tout dépend du contexte et du vouloir-dire. Différence entre quels deux mots? Vous avez vu la faute que je vous ai signalé? Un process n'est **jamais** un procès en français.

Comment: A moins d'être anatomiste ou linguiste.

Answer (score 4):

**Procès** vient du latin *processus* qui désigne l'action de s'avancer, et a d'abord et dès le moyen-âge désigné une démarche juridique.
Par un deuxième emprunt au latin au 13<sup>e</sup> siècle *procès* a pris le sens étymologique de « marche, développement, progrès ». Ce sens est désormais considéré comme vieilli et ne s'emploie plus guère qu'en philosophie ou en didactique comme le signale le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/proc%C3%A8s) qui donne comme exemple :

> Loin de nous l'idée qu'en résumant certains traits du langage des enfants nous pensions dessiner, fût-ce d'une façon approximative, le procès de l'apparition du langage dans l'espèce humaine (Arts et litt., 1935, p.50-10).

Le livre du philosophe britannique  [Whitehead](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_North_Whitehead) *Process and Reality* (1929) est traduit en français par « Procès et Réalité ».

En philosophie marxiste on parle de « [procès de travail](https://books.google.fr/books?id=s8IICwAAQBAJ&pg=PT58&lpg=PT58&dq=%22proc%C3%A8s%20de%20travail%22%20%22philosophie%20marxiste%22&source=bl&ots=HIM0FIZoOO&sig=qqUzas2Z2khX49kNGdOTpS4-4mQ&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHxqL35__MAhWLPxoKHT3KAw4Q6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=%22proc%C3%A8s%20de%20travail%22%20%22philosophie%20marxiste%22&f=false) ».

En linguistique on dit que

> le verbe est parfois défini comme exprimant un procès (du lat, *processus*, ce qui « s'avance », ce qui se passe, ce qui se déroule dans le temps); ce terme de *procès* désigne la notion générale synthétisant les notions particulières d'action, d'état, de devenir, rapportées à un sujet. (Grevisse)

**De nos jours** la majorité des francophones ne connaissent plus que le s**ens juridique du mot procès**.

Dans le domaine **technique et industriel** (*manufacturing process*) on parle de **procédé** (de fabrication, de production...) :

> [suite d'opérations mises en œuvre pour le traitement ou l'élaboration de produits industriels](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/proc%C3%A9d%C3%A9). (TLF)

Le  **processus** est une

> [Suite continue de faits, de phénomènes présentant une certaine unité ou une certaine régularité dans leur déroulement](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/processus).

La BDL de l'Office Québécois de la langue française distingue bien les [différences d'emploi](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=2247) des mots « procédé », « processus » et « procédure » qui « prêtent à confusion puisqu’ils comportent un sens commun qui est celui de " méthode" » :

> En résumé, un procédé, c’est une méthode employée pour obtenir le résultat recherché, un processus, c’est une suite d’opérations, et une procédure, c’est un ensemble de règles qu’il convient d’observer pour obtenir un résultat donné.

Pour compléter la réponse après le dernier ajout à la question il faut signaler que le mot anglais *process* est parfois traduit par « [process](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/process) » en français. C'est considéré comme un anglicisme.

Answer (score 1):

> *Procès* utilisé comme synonyme de *processus* est un terme vieilli ou littéraire.

De façon usuelle, un *procès* est le terme juridique qui constate un litige entre deux parties.

À l'origine,

> Un *procédé* est une façon d'agir envers autrui.

Mais utilisé de façon didactique,

> Un *procédé* est la forme particulière que revêt le déroulement d'un *processus*.

L'action est induite dans *procédé* qui dérive du verbe *procéder* (faire, exécuter une opération complexe).

Bien que ces termes puissent être échangés sans risques au cour d'une conversation, il y a une nuance entre les deux mots.